# increase or decrease quantity form in mobile

Tags: jquery

i am trying to  make make a product quantity form.

which can increase or decrease quantity form by touching(tapping) button...

but its hard to make jquery script to me... can anyone help me plz ?

here is my html code

```
<span><input type="text" name="minus" class="minus"></span>
<span><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="result"></span>
<span><input type="text" name="plus" class="plus"></span>
```

Comment: I just write a small code to handle this feature. you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16827830/1378146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the plus and minus options to be buttons and not text inputs based on your post. In that case your html should look like this:

```
<span><input type="button" name="minus" class="minus"></span>
<span><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" class="result"></span>
<span><input type="button" name="plus" class="plus"></span>
```

Your javascript would then be:

```
$('[name="minus"]').click(function() {
  $('#quantity').val(parseInt($('#quantity').val()) - 1);
});
$('[name="plus"]').click(function() {
  $('#quantity').val(parseInt($('#quantity').val()) + 1);
});
```